# Making bounding box for handling label collision on a map

Tags: java, latitude-longitude

In my application, I have to make an arrangement so that overlapping labels for roads/streets are handled correctly.

So I have decided to determine bounding box of each label and then check them for collisions. But I am facing an issue.

What I have with me is the lat-long coordinates of the label aligned along the road.So I have lat-long centre of the bounding box. I also have height and width of the label in meters as well as screen dots. But I am not able to decide what units the rectangle sides should be in to have correct collision detection.

Should rectangle be made with degree measurements or with meters measurements or in terms of screen dots?

Answer (score 1):

[GeoTools](http://geotools.org) has a class [LabelCacheImpl](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/renderer/label/LabelCacheImpl.java) that handles this sort of problem which you could study and adapt (it's a GPL licence) to solve your problem. Or you could just use GeoTools for the whole application.